# How to extract the domain name from URL before_create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Model with 2 attributes.

```
attr_accessible :app_url, :entity_name
```

And I am passing :app_url object value like this "www.aaronsw.com/feeds/pgessays.rss" from View.

Using before_create method in Model. The entity_name should be like this "www.aaronsw.com" (have to extract the domain name from app_url attribute)

Solution Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use ruby URI: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html

It has all that you need to accomplish your task.

```
url = URI.parse 'http://www.aaronsw.com/feeds/pgessays.rss'
url.host
 => "www.aaronsw.com"
```

Comment: also a good idea to rescue the URI:InvalidURIError in case someone enters an invalid URI